# Sort JSON by one or more properties using Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq, sorting, json.net

I have some JSON that I need to sort in C#. I'm trying to sort a list of `JObject`s using `System.Linq.Dynamic`, but I can't get it to work with instances of `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`.

**This works:**

```
public class Row
{
    public String Column1 { get; set; }
    public Int32 Column2 { get; set; }
}

var rows = new List<Row>();

rows.Add(new Row { Column1 = "B", Column2 = 2 });
rows.Add(new Row { Column1 = "B", Column2 = 1 });
rows.Add(new Row { Column1 = "A", Column2 = 2 });
rows.Add(new Row { Column1 = "A", Column2 = 1 });

var sortedRows = rows.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Column1, Column2");
```

**This does not:**

```
var rows = new List<JObject>();

var row1 = new JObject();
row1["Column1"] = "B";
row1["Column2"] = 2;
rows.Add(row1);

var row2 = new JObject();
row2["Column1"] = "B";
row2["Column2"] = 1;
rows.Add(row2);

var row3 = new JObject();
row3["Column1"] = "A";
row3["Column2"] = 2;
rows.Add(row3);

var row4 = new JObject();
row4["Column1"] = "A";
row4["Column2"] = 1;
rows.Add(row4);

var sortedRows = rows.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Column1, Column2");
//System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException : No property or field 'Column1' exists in type 'JObject'
```

How can I sort the `JObject` instances on a dynamic number of properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexer syntax from `System.Dynamic.Linq`:

```
var sortedRows = rows.AsQueryable().OrderBy(@"it[""Column1""], it[""Column2""]");
```

**Old answer**

You can't do this using `System.Linq.Dynamic`. To access `JObject`'s properties, you need to call `Property` method. However, `System.Linq.Dynamic` doesn't allow this. From the documentation:

> The expression language limits invocation of methods and constructors to those declared public in the **accessible types**.
>
> ---
>
> The expression language defines the following **primitive types**:
>
> `Object Boolean Char String SByte Byte Int16 UInt16 Int32 UInt32 Int64 UInt64 Decimal Single Double DateTime TimeSpan Guid`
>
> The primitive types correspond to the similarly named types in the System namespace of the .NET Framework Base Class Library. The expression language also defines a set of **accessible types** consisting of the primitive types and the following types from the System namespace:
>
> `Math Convert`
>
> The accessible types are the only types that can be explicitly referenced in expressions, and method invocations in the expression language are restricted to methods declared in the accessible types.

Comment: This is perfect! Saved me from implementing a terrible hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can to implement your own `IComparer` like this:

```
public class MyJObjectComparer : IComparer<JObject>
{
    public int Compare(JObject a, JObject b)
    {
        if ((a["Column1"] == b["Column1"]) && a["Column2"] == b["Column2"]))
            return 0;

        if ((a["Column1"] < b["Columnq"]) || ((a["Column1"] == b["Column1"]) && (a["Column2"] < b["Column2"])))
            return -1;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var sortedRows = rows.AsQueryable().OrderBy(r => r, new MyJObjectComparer());
```